# correct kill syscall linux usage pattern

Tags: c, linux, security, system, system-calls

[man](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) for `int kill(pid_t pid, int sig);` says:

> If pid equals -1, then sig is sent to every process for which the
>   calling process has permission to send signals, except for process 1
>   (init), but see below.

Does this mean that if my program is run with root permissions and it accidentally (due to memory corruption or a hack) provides `-1` as `pid` argument - this will cause a complete DoS for the entire system?

If so, is it recommended to always perform a double check for the `pid` argument value before calling this potentially disasterous call? *(just sayin')*

Comment: Why would your program be run with root permissions again?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi how is that relevant to the question?  Obviously there exist programs which need to run as root.  Let's assume we are talking about them.

Comment: @John, then those programs should observe the utmost care when operating in *any* situation, not just when calling `kill()`. There are a gazillion ways to screw your system if you tread lightly with syscalls while being root, and `kill()` is not special in that respect -- `write()` is actually worse. Now should we double-check that `write()` does not touch an MBR just in case of *memory corruption or a hack*?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Why not merge your two comments into an answer?

Comment: @alk, because it would not really be about programming *per se*. It would basically amount to *do not run your programs as root*, which does not bring much to the table, answer-wise. Incidentally, I'm quite sure this question is off-topic.

Comment: "*off-topic*" fair enough. @FrédéricHamidi

Comment: I would accept *do not run your programs as root* as an answer here - as it resolves my issues. Almost any userspace program can be configured to run as non-privileged user and it should be done

Comment: I wouldn't consider a question about a specific system call as off-topic. The question may be a "what-if" kind and have a trivial answer. But IMO, that's not enough to consider off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this mean that if my program is run with root permissions and it
>   accidentally (due to memory corruption or a hack) provides -1 as pid
>   argument - this will cause a complete DoS for the entire system?

Yes, such a scenario is possible. But the chances of it happening is very less. Because no program that run with root permissions would do such a thing. If a malicious user/binary has somehow got gained root privilege, then sending signals is just one of the problems.

> If so, is it recommended to always perform a double check for the pid
>   argument value before calling this potentially disastrous call?

That's just super paranoid thinking. There are thousands of ways to do disastrous activities.You might as well worry about:

What if there's not malicious daemon, ran at system startup, does:

```
kill(-1, SIGKILL);
```

How do you know if library function you make wouldn't call `reboot(2)` and reboot your system?

etc.

Besides, PIDs are not just user provided values that need to be sanitized. PIDs are mostly values acquired within the program using system calls or library calls. So the chances of "accidentally" using -1 is zero. Basically, you someone/program has root privilege and decided to screw your system then there's not much you can do.